# Optimal strategy - HJB equation - Change to Mathematics

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, hamilton-jacobi-equation

I am sitting with the following control problem.

Given know the controlled Markov equation
\begin{align}
dX_t&=-\lambda X_t\cdot dt+ U_t\cdot dt+\sigma\sqrt{1+X_t^2}\cdot dB_t
\end{align}
with the performance objective function

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^T \left(\frac{1}{2}qX_t^2+\frac{1}{2}U_t^2\right)dt +\frac{1}{2}\alpha\cdot X_T^2\right]
\end{align}

The goals is to minimize the performance function over all Markov controls $U_t=\mu(X_t,t)$.

Furthermore, I want to determine a $\alpha>0$ such that for all $q>0$, the optimal control does not depend on $t$, i.e. $U_t=\mu(X_t)$.

Question: The question I have here is how to determine the $\alpha>0$ such that for all $q>0$, $U_t=\mu(X_t)$.

Does anybody have an idea?